# Bash script with a python instruction inside - doesn't work

Tags: bash

I am starting with programming and trying to access three folders namely 5, 10, 20 and execute a python script in there.

For that purpose i wrote:

```
   for folder in /5 /10 /20
        do 
            echo -n $folder
            cd folder
            python scripts_1/thermo-analisis-de-datos.py
        done
```

It is not working :(. Any help?

Comment: Presume the cd folder line isn't working?  You've missed off the leading dollar sign.  Also, any path starting with a slash is absolute, whereas I suspect that you want paths relative to your working directory?  Omit the leading slashes if so.  Is scripts_1 a subfolder of folders 5, 10, 20?  If not your python invocation line will need to be revised to find it.

Comment: great, everything you say was correct. I will try again @martinclayton. Thanks